# Display server starting time in JSF

Tags: jsf, time, wildfly

As seen on footer of the [OmniFaces showcase site](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) (scroll to very bottom of page).

> Server (re)started at 12 Jun 2015 08:50 UTC

How can I display the time of the last server restart/start or/and the last update of the quellcode, if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OmniFaces showcase is also [open source](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/). You can find the responsible code in [line 100 of `/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml`](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml#L100)

```
<p>Server (re)started at #{of:formatDateWithTimezone(startup, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm', 'UTC')} UTC</p>
```

It's thus using OmniFaces own [`#{startup}` managed bean](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/managedbeans/startup) for this which is basically registered as below in OmniFaces own [`faces-config.xml`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml#L53):

```
<managed-bean eager="true">
    <managed-bean-name>startup</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In "plain JSF" you could show it as below:

```
<h:outputText value="#{startup}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="d MMM yyyy HH:mm" />
</h:outputText>
```