# CSS #{resource} versioning

Tags: css, jsf, resources, background-image, versioning

How to do versioning or force browser clear cache for image resources in CSS resources?

use this code in my css:

```
.applicationLogo {
    background: url("#{resource['images:invoicePa.png']}") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, append a version query string. It could be done statically

```
background: url("#{resource['images:invoicePa.png']}?1") no-repeat 0 0;
```

or dynamically based on e.g. [server startup time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427413/display-server-starting-time-in-jsf/).

```
background: url("#{resource['images:invoicePa.png']}?#{startup.time}") no-repeat 0 0;
```

or even on resource's own timestamp (which is relatively expensive to check though).

```
background: url("#{resource['images:invoicePa.png']}?#{facesContext.externalContext.getResource('/resources/images/invoicePa.png').openConnection().lastModified}") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Alternative is to simply rename the file.

```
background: url("#{resource['images:invoice_payment.png']}") no-repeat 0 0;
```